# first time login jqxgrid show error like adapter after refers it show error

Tags: php, codeigniter, jqxgrid

First time loading page in server it show error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataAdapter' of undefined

after refers it will working. Then after refers it show again same error.

And jqxgrid are not working in mobile view show error like

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: you are json is in not correct format

Comment: what is correct format can you explain to it... in jqxgrid

Comment: Refer google aboit json and parsing of json